# determining whether a position is a member of a particular list

Tags: c++

I have the following List class:

```
typedef int Elem;               // list base element type
  class NodeList {              // node-based list
  private:
    struct Node {               // a node of the list
      Elem elem;                // element value
      Node* prev;               // previous in list
      Node* next;               // next in list
    };
  public:
    class Iterator {                // an iterator for the list
    public:
      Elem& operator*();            // reference to the element
      bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const; // compare positions
      bool operator!=(const Iterator& p) const;
      Iterator& operator++();           // move to next position
      Iterator& operator--();           // move to previous position
      friend class NodeList;            // give NodeList access
    private:
      Node* v;                  // pointer to the node
      Iterator(Node* u);            // create from node
    };
  public:
    NodeList();                 // default constructor
    int size() const;               // list size
    bool empty() const;             // is the list empty?
    Iterator begin() const;         // beginning position
    Iterator end() const;           // (just beyond) last position
    void insertFront(const Elem& e);        // insert at front
    void insertBack(const Elem& e);     // insert at rear
    void insert(const Iterator& p, const Elem& e); // insert e before p
    void eraseFront();              // remove first
    void eraseBack();               // remove last
    void erase(const Iterator& p);      // remove p
  private:                  // data members
    int     n;                  // number of items
    Node*   header;             // head-of-list sentinel
    Node*   trailer;                // tail-of-list sentinel
  };
```

My code does not do any checking to determine whether a given position (iterator object) is actually a member of a particular list. For example, if p is a position in list S and I call T.insert(p,e) on a different list T, then I'd actually be adding the element to S just before p. How can I change my NodeList implementation to disallow such a misuse?

Comment: Couldn't you just make it static?

Comment: Supposedly I need to use either a new field in a position object or a new query function in a list.

Comment: `std::list` has the similar behavior([Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a1fe493224aec77d1a91b5e182b0a7bd-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have Iterator store a pointer to the NodeList that owns it.

```
class Iterator {                // an iterator for the list
public:
  Elem& operator*();            // reference to the element
  bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const; // compare positions
  bool operator!=(const Iterator& p) const;
  Iterator& operator++();           // move to next position
  Iterator& operator--();           // move to previous position
  friend class NodeList;            // give NodeList access
private:
  Node* v;                  // pointer to the node
  NodeList* plist;
  Iterator(Node* u,NodeList* p);            // create from node

};
```

When you create the Iterator path this as the NodeList. Then in your insert method, check that your Iterator.plist == this